# jQuery ui dialog custom close functions

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog

I am trying to find a way to call custom functions for close and save using my jQuery UI dialog.

```
$("#checkbox-confirm").dialog({
    width: 600,
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    responsive: true,
    close: function() {
      // special things happen when they click the cancel button
      $(this).dialog("close");
    },
    save: function() {
      // also some special things then close the dialog
    }
});

$(".btn-cancel").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#checkbox-confirm").dialog("close");
});

$(".btn-save").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#checkbox-confirm").dialog("save")
});
```

My buttons are separate from my dialog like:

```
<div id="#checkbox-confirm">
   modal things here 
   <button class="btn-cancel>Cancel</button>
   <button class="btn-save">Save</button>
</div>
```

Is this even possible or should I find another way to implement?

Comment: `save` is not a Event or Method of `dialog`, so this will not work. I would create standalone functions that then close the `dialog` upon completion.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably move the buttons into the modal window.  The concept behind a modal is that some content is forced to the user's attention (typically above the previous content) and awaiting some sort of response (close, submit, etc).

That being said, it is possible to control a modal with external buttons/controls.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following:

```
$("#checkbox-confirm").dialog({
    width: 600,
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    responsive: true,
    _allowInteractions: function(e){
      return !!$(e.target).is("#checkbox-confirm button") || this._super(e);
    }
});

$(".btn-cancel").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // Do special Cancel stuff
  $("#checkbox-confirm").dialog("close");
});

$(".btn-save").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // Do Special Save Stuff
  $("#checkbox-confirm").dialog("close");
});
```

Personally, I would NOT move the buttons out of the button set and instead make your Dialog less visible.

**CSS**

```
.mini-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar {
  display: none;
}

.mini-dilaog .ui-dialog-buttonpane {
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#checkbox-confirm").dialog({
    dialogClass: "mini-dialog",
    width: 600,
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    responsive: true,
    buttons: [{
      text: "Cancel",
      class: "btn-cancel",
      click: function(){
        // special things happen when they click the cancel button
        $(this).dialog("close");
      }
    },
    {
      text: "Save",
      class: "btn-save",
      click: function(){
        // also some special things then close the dialog
        $(this).dialog("close");
      }
    }]
});

$("#checkbox-confirm").on("dialogopen" function(e){
  $(this).css("display", "none");
});
```

This will hide the Titlebar and Content, leaving only the Button Set. User is forced to hit Save or Cancel due to Modal.